# Jest Error - Your test suite must contain at least one test

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

My versions are:

- Vue 2.6.14 (cannot be upgraded)
- Jest & Babel Jest 26.6.3
- @vue/test-utils 1.3.0

I have the following test inside `AppFooter.test.js`:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import AppFooter from './AppFooter.vue';

describe("AppFooter.vue", () => {
    test("dummy test", () => {
        expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
    });
    
    test("AppFooter mounts", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(AppFooter);
        expect(wrapper.contains('footer')).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

And test output is:

```
FAIL  components/AppFooter.test.js

  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.
```

If I bump Jest up to 29.*.* and leave just the test unrelated to Vue, like this:

```
test("dummy test", () => {
    expect(1 + 2).toBe(3);
});
```

then it works ok. But if I start importing Vue components, it doesn't work due to version mismatch. So I need to use Jest 26 for Vue 2.6, which brings me again to the issue of test suit having no tests.

Command + click on `describe`, `test` and `expect` seems to show correct relations (for example, for `declare`, it shows `jest.Describe`) so there should be no issue there.

Jest config is:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'vue', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'vue-jest',
    '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest'
  },
  collectCoverage: false
};
```

Any ideas what to try?